# If φ is a homomorphism, φ: G⟶G′, |G| and |G'| is finite, then for every g ∈ G, o(φ(g)) | (g.c.d(|G|,|G'|))

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Assume $φ:G⟶G'$
is a homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$.

prove:

if $|G|,|G'|$ is finite then: **$o(φ(g) | (g.c.d(|G|,|G'|))$.**

- **My proof**:

φ is homomorphism so we know **$o(φ(g))|o(g)$**
& G is a group so **$o(g)||G|$**

From the transitivity of the division relation we can conclude **$o(φ(g))|(|G|)$.**

from obvious reason φ(g)∈G' and G' is a group so **$o(φ(g))|(|G'|)$.**

So far I have,

$o(φ(g))|(|G|)$

$o(φ(g))|(|G'|)$

but the next step, mean **$o(φ(g)) | (g.c.d(|G|,|G'|))$**, is somewhat un-clear to me.

**how can this move be done ?**

thank you!

Comment: $a|b,a|c\implies a | \gcd(b,c).$

Comment: So basically you have $o(\varphi(g))$ divides two numbers, and you want to show it must divide the gcd of those two numbers. This is just a fact about integers; no group theory required! My preferred way of showing that if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|(\gcd(b,c))$ is to use Bezout's identity

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: it is. i'm working on the MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind guys, here it is:

prove:

##### **if a|b and a|c then a|gcd(b,c).**

---

proof:

a|b so exist integer n such that an = b
a|c so exist integer m such that am = c

define d = gcd(b,c).

then, exist integers x,y such that xb + yc = d.

then x(an) + y(am) = d

then a(xn + ym) = d

then a | d = gcd(b,c).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242). It's best for site health to delete this duplicate Q&A.

Comment: i get an error: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Comment: You need to first unaccept this answer then delete it. Then you can delete the quesiton.